# Access immutable methods while iterating over a mutable member

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

While learning about iterators in Rust, I created the following struct to hide the implementation of a two-dimensional collection:

```
use std::slice::{Items, MutItems};
use std::vec::{Vec};

pub struct Table<T> {
    pub width: uint,
    pub height: uint,
    data: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: Clone> Table<T> {
    pub fn from_elem(width: uint, height: uint, value: T) -> Table<T> {
        Table {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            data: Vec::from_elem(width * height, value)
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Table<T> {
    pub fn get_row_column(&self, index: uint) -> (uint, uint) {
        (index / self.width, index % self.width)
    }

    pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Items<'a, T> {
        self.data.iter()
    }

    pub fn iter_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> MutItems<'a, T> {
        self.data.iter_mut()
    }
}
```

The goal of the `iter` and `iter_mut` methods was that the user of this struct wouldn't need to worry about whether the data was stored in a row-major or column-major format; the iterator would simply provide the elements in the most efficient order.

However, in using this data structure, I often needed to know the particular row and column in order to get some external data:

```
fn get_input(row: uint, column: uint) -> uint {
    row * 10 + column / 2
}

fn main() {
    let mut table = Table::from_elem(640, 480, 0u);

    for (index, value) in table.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        let (row, column) = table.get_row_column(index);
        *value = get_input(row, column);
    }
}
```

But as soon as I try to call the `get_row_column` method, I get the following compiler error:

```
main.rs:56:33: 56:38 error: cannot borrow `table` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
main.rs:56             let (row, column) = table.get_row_column(index);
                                           ^~~~~
main.rs:55:31: 55:36 note: previous borrow of `table` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `table` until the borrow ends
main.rs:55         for (index, value) in table.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                                         ^~~~~
main.rs:59:6: 59:6 note: previous borrow ends here
main.rs:55         for (index, value) in table.iter_mut().enumerate() {
main.rs:56             let (row, column) = table.get_row_column(index);
main.rs:57             *value = get_input(row, column);
main.rs:58         }
main.rs:59     }
               ^
```

**What's the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?**  I can add a `set` method that takes the row and column numbers and explicitly loop over row and column indices, but then the user has to worry about row-major vs. column-major ordering:

```
impl<T> Table<T> {        
    fn get_index(&self, row: uint, column: uint) -> uint {
        row * self.width + column
    }

    pub fn set(&mut self, row: uint, column: uint, value: T) {
        let index = self.get_index(row, column);
        self.data[index] = value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut table = Table::from_elem(640, 480, 0u);

    for row in range(0, table.height) {
        for column in range(0, table.width) {
            table.set(row, column, get_input(row, column));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a convention or best-practice for mutating internal members of a struct while still allowing access to the immutable members and methods? Or does that completely violate the safety guarantees?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make `width` and `height` public? Anybody could change their value and everything would break! They should be exposed through getter methods instead.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Oops! That's a very good point. I've been lazily assuming that everything in Rust would be immutable, but that's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthieu M. has the right idea: use the iterator to return the `row` and `column`, rather than directly expose `index`.  Unfortunately, it appears that closures in Rust are currently stack allocated and cannot extend beyond the stack frame in which they were created, so his proposed solution doesn't compile.

While using the iterator adapters is extremely convenient and succinct, we can still do it the long way by creating new iterators objects.

The key is to create an iterator that keeps track of the context we need, which in this case is the dimensions of the table:

```
pub struct TableItems<'a, T: 'a> {
    iter: Items<'a, T>,
    width: uint,
    height: uint
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator<&'a T> for TableItems<'a, T> {
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}
```

This struct contains the `Items` iterator provided by the `slice` module, along with the `width` and `height` from the table.  Implementing the `Iterator` trait is as easy as passing along the call to `next` to the internal iterator.

The `TableItems` struct only returns immutable references, but we can create a similar one for mutable references:

```
pub struct MutTableItems<'a, T: 'a> {
    iter: MutItems<'a, T>,
    width: uint,
    height: uint
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator<&'a mut T> for MutTableItems<'a, T> {
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut T> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}
```

Then we just need to add a way to pass the dimensions from the `Table` object into the iterators:

```
impl<T> Table<T> {
    pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> TableItems<'a, T> {
        TableItems {
            iter: self.data.iter(),
            width: self.width,
            height: self.height
        }
    }

    pub fn iter_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> MutTableItems<'a, T> {
        MutTableItems {
            iter: self.data.iter_mut(),
            width: self.width,
            height: self.height
        }
    }
}
```

Now, these iterators by themselves don't really gain us anything; they return the values of the `Table`, but we still don't have the `row` and `column`.  To accomplish that, we can add our own iterator adapter that mimics the `Enumerate` trait from the `iter` module by incrementing separate counts for the current row and column:

```
impl<'a, A, T: Iterator<A>> Iterator<((uint, uint), A)> for TableEnumerate<T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<((uint, uint), A)> {
        match self.iter.next() {
            Some(value) => {
                let ret = Some(((self.row_count, self.column_count), value));

                self.column_count += 1;
                if self.column_count == self.width {
                    self.row_count += 1;
                    self.column_count = 0;
                }
                ret
            },
            None => None
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (uint, Option<uint>) {
        self.iter.size_hint()
    }
}
```

This adapter is generic, so it can be used for either `TableItems` or `MutTableItems` (or anything else we choose to come up with in the future).

The last step is to create methods that return an instance of `TableEnumerate`:

```
impl<'a, T> TableItems<'a, T> {
    pub fn enumerate_2d(self) -> TableEnumerate<TableItems<'a, T>> {
        let width = self.width;
        let height = self.height;

        TableEnumerate {
            iter: self,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            row_count: 0,
            column_count: 0
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> MutTableItems<'a, T> {
    pub fn enumerate_2d(self) -> TableEnumerate<MutTableItems<'a, T>> {
        let width = self.width;
        let height = self.height;

        TableEnumerate {
            iter: self,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            row_count: 0,
            column_count: 0
        }
    }
}
```

I would have loved to have named these `enumerate`, but it appears that the compiler finds the `Iterator` implementation of `enumerate` before this one.

With this complete solution, the table can be acessed like so:

```
fn get_input(row: uint, column: uint) -> uint {
    row * 10 + column / 2
}

fn main() {
    let mut table = Table::from_elem(640, 480, 0u);

    for ((row, column), value) in table.iter_mut().enumerate_2d() {
        *value = get_input(row, column);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a mutable-immutable issue, it's just a double-borrow. If the inner method call was an `&mut self` method you would have the same issues. You haven't lost access to the immutable methods, you have lost access to *all* methods as long as `value` is in scope, since `value` is a borrow into the table.

While it's not happening in this particular case, having multiple aliases to the piece being iterated over can lead to iterator invalidation.

In this case, use `map` to do the calculations:

```
fn main() {
    let mut table = Table::from_elem(640, 480, 0u);
    let width = table.width;

    for (value, row, column) in table.iter_mut().enumerate().map(|(i,v)| (v, i / width, i % width) ) {
        *value = get_input(row, column);
    }
}
```

[playpen](http://is.gd/iFJM1C)

Making `get_row_column` a separate function would help, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the issue here is one of *leaky abstraction*: `index` should never be exposed to the user to start with.

Therefore, you would need to change the interface to directly provide `(row, column)` instead of `index` when iterating, and then usage would be straightforward.

Something like:

```
use std::iter::{Enumerate, Map}

impl<T> Table<T> {
    // Additions
    pub fn iter_enum<'a>(&'a self) -> Map<'a, (uint, &'a T), ((uint, uint), &'a T), Enumerate<Items<'a, T>>> {
        self.iter().enumerate().map(|(i, v)| ((i / self.width, i % self.width), v)
    }

    pub fn iter_mut_enum<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Map<'a, (uint, &'a mut T), ((uint, uint), &'a mut T), Enumerate<MutItems<'a, T>>> {
        self.iter_mut().enumerate().map(|(i, v)| ((i / self.width, i % self.width), v)
    }
}
```

*Note: I wish for C++ template aliases feature a lot, here.*

Comment: I really like this, but I haven't been able to get it to compile due to errors about `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'r in function call due to conflicting requirements`.